# Importing dbatools module into Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, dbatools

Has anyone managed to import dbatools module into Azure Automation Account? I tried to do it in several ways, but every time the installation fails:

- different versions checked from 0.9.* to the latest 1.0.9
- from portal using Automation Accounts -> Automation modules -> Browse Gallery
- from portal using Automation Accounts -> Automation modules -> import from file

Every time I got:

> Error importing the module dbatools. Import failed with the following
>   error: Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: An
>   error occurred during module validation. When importing the module to
>   an internal PowerShell session, it was not able to be loaded by
>   PowerShell. There is likely an issue with the contents of the module
>   that results in PowerShell's not being able to load it. Please verify
>   that the module imports successfully in a local PowerShell session,
>   correct any issues, and then try importing again.

As you can see the error message doesn't tell much (and obviously I am able to import it locally), thus I wonder if anyone managed to go over it somehow.

Comment: You'd be better off posting this on [their github](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools)

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/issues/5835

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with importing `dbatools` into Azure Automation Accounts has been resolved as of release `1.0.66`...

[image]
https://twitter.com/wsmelton/status/1191370349390303234